# Problem mapping on Android Studio in Java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I encounter a problem with my code, and I would be interested in the concrete explanation of one concept. Basically, I understood how the SharedPreferences are working, I know the key-values concept, but although i searched on the official documentation and other websites, I cannot figure how the Mapping is working.

I'm making an app that is a "M.Mood" like. When user scroll up or down, the mood and color of mood is changing. When you click on history, you have a new screen in a new Activity that displays the 7 last days values.

Here is my problem : I retrieved the SharedPreferences from my MainActivity.java in my HistoryActivity.java, I tried to map it, but then the color of my TextViews stay red. Being a beginner in Java, i would like to have your opinion on why it is not displaying colors that i registered on my colors.xml resources.

Here is my MainActivity.java file :

```
package com.lepanda.studioneopanda.moodtracker;

// all my imports

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
SimpleGestureDetector.SimpleGestureListener {

ImageButton comment;
ImageButton history;
EditText input;
ImageView iv;
RelativeLayout container;
int tableMood[] = {R.drawable.smiley_sad, R.drawable.smiley_disappointed, R.drawable.smiley_normal, R.drawable.smiley_happy, R.drawable.smiley_super_happy};
int currentMood;
int tableColor[] = {R.color.faded_red, R.color.warm_grey, R.color.cornflower_blue_65, R.color.light_sage, R.color.banana_yellow};
int currentColor;
int currentComColor;
int currentHisColor;

private SimpleGestureDetector detector;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    iv = findViewById(R.id.iv);
    currentMood = 3;
    iv.setImageResource(tableMood[currentMood]);

    container = findViewById(R.id.container);
    currentColor = 3;
    container.setBackgroundResource(tableColor[currentColor]);

    comment = findViewById(R.id.comment);
    currentComColor = 3;
    comment.setBackgroundResource(tableColor[currentComColor]);

    history = findViewById(R.id.history);
    currentHisColor = 3;
    history.setBackgroundResource(tableColor[currentHisColor]);

    // Detect touched area
    detector = new SimpleGestureDetector(MainActivity.this, this);

    //history button click + sharedpref and manage calendar

//Creating the dialog box prompting user for a message
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Add comment");
    builder.setMessage("Comment vous sentez-vous ?");

    input = new EditText(this);
    builder.setView(input);

    //Create PositiveButton
    builder.setPositiveButton("Enregistrer", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            String txt = input.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), txt, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    //Create NegativeButton
    builder.setNegativeButton("Annuler", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    final AlertDialog ad = builder.create();
    //Button
    comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ad.show();
        }
    });

    ImageButton history = findViewById(R.id.history);
    history.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startHistory();
        }
    });

    if (getMood() != tableMood[currentMood]){
        iv.setImageResource(tableMood[getMood()]);
    }
}

private void startHistory() {
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HistoryActivity.class));
}

@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent me) {
    // Call onTouchEvent of SimpleGestureFilter class
    this.detector.onTouchEvent(me);
    return super.dispatchTouchEvent(me);
}

@Override
public void onSwipe(int direction) {

    //Detect the swipe gestures and display toast
    String showToastMessage = "";

    switch (direction) {

        case SimpleGestureDetector.SWIPE_UP:
            showToastMessage = "You have Swiped Up.";
            if (currentMood == 4) {
                showToastMessage = "Vous êtes vraiment si content ?";
            } else {
                currentMood++;
                iv.setImageResource(tableMood[currentMood]);
                currentColor++;
                container.setBackgroundResource(tableColor[currentColor]);
                currentComColor++;
                comment.setBackgroundResource(tableColor[currentComColor]);
                currentHisColor++;
                history.setBackgroundResource(tableColor[currentHisColor]);
                storeMood(currentMood);

            }
            break;

        case SimpleGestureDetector.SWIPE_DOWN:
            showToastMessage = "You have Swiped Down.";
            if (currentMood == 0) {
                showToastMessage = "Vous êtes vraiment si malheureux ?";
            } else {
                currentMood--;
                iv.setImageResource(tableMood[currentMood]);
                currentColor--;
                container.setBackgroundResource(tableColor[currentColor]);
                currentComColor--;
                comment.setBackgroundResource(tableColor[currentComColor]);
                currentHisColor--;
                history.setBackgroundResource(tableColor[currentHisColor]);
                storeMood(currentMood);
            }
            break;
    }
    Toast.makeText(this, showToastMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}


public void storeMood(int mood) {
    SharedPreferences msharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("monP3", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor = msharedPreferences.edit();
    String dayNumberKey = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyyMMddhms", new java.util.Date()).toString();
    mEditor.putInt(dayNumberKey, mood);
    mEditor.apply();
}
private int getMood(){
    SharedPreferences msharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("monP3", MODE_PRIVATE);
    String dayNumberKey = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyyMMddhms", new java.util.Date()).toString();
    int actualMood = msharedPreferences.getInt(dayNumberKey, currentMood);
    return actualMood;
}
```

}

Here is my HistoryActivity.java file :

```
package com.lepanda.studioneopanda.moodtracker;

// imports

public class HistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

int tableMood[] = {R.drawable.smiley_sad, R.drawable.smiley_disappointed, R.drawable.smiley_normal, R.drawable.smiley_happy, R.drawable.smiley_super_happy};
int tableColor[] = {R.color.faded_red, R.color.warm_grey, R.color.cornflower_blue_65, R.color.light_sage, R.color.banana_yellow};

int currentColor;
int currenMood;

TextView view1;
TextView view2;
TextView view3;
TextView view4;
TextView view5;
TextView view6;
TextView view7;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);

    SharedPreferences msharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("monP3", MODE_PRIVATE);

    view1 = findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    view2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    view3 = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    view4 = findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    view5 = findViewById(R.id.textView5);
    view6 = findViewById(R.id.textView6);
    view7 = findViewById(R.id.textView7);

    TextView[] histos = {view1, view2, view3, view4, view5, view6, view7};

    Map<String, ?> allEntries = msharedPreferences.getAll();

    String dayNumberKey = android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyyMMddhms", new java.util.Date()).toString();

    int myCol = msharedPreferences.getInt(dayNumberKey, currenMood);

    if (myCol == 0){
        currentColor = 0;
    }
    else if (myCol == 1){
        currentColor = 1;
    }
    else if (myCol == 2){
        currentColor = 2;
    }
    else if (myCol == 3){
        currentColor = 3;
    }
    else if (myCol == 4){
        currentColor = 4;
    }

    int i = 0;

    for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : allEntries.entrySet()) {
        histos[i].setText(entry.getValue().toString());
        i++;
        if(i > 6) break;
        histos[i].setBackgroundResource(tableColor[currentColor]);
    }
}
```

}

Voilà, I really would like to understand why only the red color is displayed when I click on the history Button. 
I'm sure it's something little, but as I said, I am a total beginner.

Thank you !

Solution : I removed the dynamic key that i tried to use at different places with different values

Comment: Android Studio (IDE) and Android (OS) are 2 different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the current date and time as key to store the color and using another date and time to retrieve it. The return values of the two calls of `android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyyMMddhms", new java.util.Date()).toString()` will be different. Use the same value (a constant value) for store and retrieve the data that you want to use.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. If I understand correctly, your suggestion is that I replace my dynamic key with a static one, like "key" ? Because if I do so, my problem will be that my app won't know when the day is different, and the history is based on this dynamic key.

Comment: Exactly. At the next second, the return value of java.util.Date() will be different and you won't be able the retrieve the data previously stored.

Comment: If so, I would need to use the var currentMood to get the value changing in function of the Image, do you have an idea how to retrieve this var in my HistoryActivity ? I was thinking that the mapping would retrieve all the values stored in the SharedPreferences of my MainActivity, but it seems it isn't :(

Comment: You want a single register for each day?

Comment: Yes, I need to put every day of the last week into the history, each one of them being represented by a TextView in my activity_history.xml, I try to make the color change in function of the smiley displayed in the activity_main.xml

Comment: Change to android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyyMMdd", new java.util.Date()).toString() in the method "storeMood" and "getMood". Inside the HistoryActivity you will need to specify a day to retrieve the data, if you want only the current day, change the retrieve key too. This is assuming that you can't edit past days. I don't know your application, but consider using SQLite, if your data are going to be big, https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room